# How can I change the height of a cell when it is selected?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have looked around for other answers but can not seem to get anything working. I have implemented this code:

```
var selectedCellIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
let selectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 88.0
let unselectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 51.0

// Override to support editing of individual itemCells

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if selectedCellHeight == indexPath {
        return selectedCellHeight
    }
    return unselectedCellHeight
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if selectedCellIndexPath != nil && selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
        self.selectedCellIndexPath = nil
    } else {
        self.selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
    }

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

    if selectedCellIndexPath != nil {
        // THis ensure, that the cell is full visile once expended 
        tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .None, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And I got it from other StackOverFlow answers, but when I run my application the cell only shows that it is selected (by being shaded) and then performs no other actions. Any help will be great! I am a beginning developer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if selectedCellHeight == indexPath {
```

should be

```
if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
```

Comment: Thank you, @Aaron Brager! Im still novice so this was not as simple to see for me! I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @KeithFrazier98 Happy to help! If this resolved your issue, please click the checkbox to the left of my answer. (This will signal to other users that you no longer need help.)